# Find the condition when exactly one root of given quadratic equation lies in the given interval

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Let $f(x)=x^2-2px+p^2-1$, then find the condition when exactly one root of given quadratic equation lies in the interval $\left(-2,4\right)$

My attempt is as follows:

$$x^2-2px+p^2-1=0$$
$$\left(x-p\right)^2=1$$
$$x=p-1,p+1 $$

Case 1: Only $p-1$ will lie in the interval $\left(-2,4\right)$ if $-2<p-1<4<=p+1$. Solving this would give $p\in \left[3,5\right)$

Case 2: Only $p+1$ will lie in the interval $\left(-2,4\right)$ if $p-1<=-2<p+1<4$. Solving this would give $p\in \left(-3,-1\right]$

Taking union of case 1,case 2 would give $p\in (-3,-1] \cup [3,5)$

But actual answer is $p\in (-3,-1) \cup (3,5)$

I don't understand what mistake am I doing here?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: @user3290550 I also agree with Peter Foreman that your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct and the provided one is wrong. To check yourself, the only place your solution differs is in the $p$ values of $-1$ and $3$. Substituting, we get the equations $x(x+2)=0$ and $(x-4)(x-2)=0$ respectively, both of which satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to $$x^2-2p+p^2-1=0$$ are $$x=p\pm 1$$

That gives us $$p\in (-3,-1]\cup [3,5)$$

Comment: At p=-4 , it does not satisfy, as p=-5,-3 , as no root lies in the interval (-2,4)

Comment: @user3290550  Thanks for the comment . Check the edit please

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani The question asks for having *exactly* one root in $(-2,4)$. Note at $p = 3$ the roots are $2$ and $4$, so it provides just one root in the requested range (as $4 \not\in (-2,4)$) and, thus, it should be included in the range of values. Likewise, $p = -1$ should also be included.

Comment: @John  Omielan Thanks, check the edit please